# Straight cuts in plywood without a circular saw

Tags: plywood, hand-planing, hand-saw, jigsaw

I'm looking to make some drawer boxes out of plywood, and don't think I have enough space to set up to feel safe using a circular saw (certainly no room for a table saw).

Popular opinion seems to be that you can't cut straight with a (handheld) jigsaw. But with it against a straight edge clamped as makeshift fence, how can it be worse than (my amateur) hand sawing? Does the blade really wobble side to side that much?

Can plywood be (hand) planed, or does the glue gum up too much? If so I would think a jigsaw wobble cut & planing would still be faster/better overall than by (my inexperienced) hand?

Comment: I'm glad you added that last paragraph as that's exactly what I was going to suggest. In hand-tool woodworking you will nearly always plane a sawn surface, and this holds if you're working with ply. Now since you did ask this already, the site's in-built Related feature handily has [this Q&A](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/27) at the top. I haven't looked at all of it again but there's sure to be something in that which will help you get better results (and obviously you can confidently saw knowing you will get accurately to your line afterwards by planing). [contd]

Comment: Re. popular opinion and the jigsaw though, well you're right to be sceptical about it! The (many) people who say this are either blindly repeating a 'fact' they've heard, or they're relating their own experience *where they did it wrong*. Cos yes, you can get quite a decent straight cut with a jigsaw if you use the right blade, *and saw slowly*. From what I've seen, virtually every bad jigsaw cut (where it doesn't track the line well) is down to the user sawing too quickly. Anyway, I'll flesh out a proper Answer for you later if nobody has added a good one in the meantime.

Comment: BTW re. hand planing plywood, you will likely need to sharpen a little more frequently than normal but it shouldn't be too bad. I recently had cause to plane OSB, which is way tougher than a typical plywood, and even that wasn't too bad.... with BTW stock irons in non-premium planes, so not using A2, PMV-11 or anything like that :-)

Comment: Thanks @Graphus. I think I'll try hand sawing (and planing) first, but buy a jigsaw if it seems it'll take unenjoyably long. To be honest my intuition is that my hand sawn cuts are going to be worse than a jigsawn cut, so I might get one anyway if that turns out to be true, since for now at least I'm more interested in the drawers (and some other aspects of making them) than in making every cut 5 times for practice and once for real to develop good technique!

Comment: I don't want to diminish your enthusiasm for hand-cut drawer bodies, but what is the goal here? The experience of building, or the final product? If it's the final product, then ping back for some alternatives.

Comment: PS, forget guides with jigsaws -- they do more harm than good.

Comment: Will you bring home full sheets of plywood or can you get cuts done where you buy? If they will cut strips you only then need to do crosscuts to length needed .

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, uh, what?

Comment: @Graphus -- are we talking about guides and jigsaws? If so, I stand by what I wrote: guides won't help if (when) the blade wanders a little bit, and jigsaws (by their nature) won't force themselves back onto a line -- the blade just gets progressively skewed. Using a super high end jigsaw and blades can help, but I'm convinced one will get a better result from slowly following a line.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, yes in relation to guides. Even just a straightedge is a huge boon IME, and various commercial and DIY guide systems work extremely well from what I've seen; your interpretation mileage may vary, but the demos sure convinced me. I take it as a given with jigsaws that you should let it cut at its own pace but I suppose it's worth emphasising in case that's not obvious to anyone, a guide is not a pass for suddenly have the saw cut X times faster.

Comment: Agree completely that too much speed/pushing too hard with a jigsaw (and probably most other cutting things) is not a good thing.

Comment: "don't think I have enough space to set up to feel safe using a circular saw." **Premise is flawed.** The thing you need space for is the sheet of plywood. The circular saw sits _on top_ of the plywood, _just like a jig-saw will_. It takes _zero_ extra space. Unless you're trying to rip a 4x8' sheet into 2@ 4x4' sheets, the jig saw will buy you _nothing_ over a circular saw. The only advantage it will gain you is that it's easier to handle with one hand when stretching, **BUT** you loose _significant_ accuracy in your cut with one hand.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you so much, I thought the saw went in an adjacent room.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Both.

Comment: Then please explain your concern about the added space a circular saw would take up vs using a jig saw or hand saw, because I am _honestly_ very confused by your statement. A table saw, yeah, those take up a lot of space - I keep having to move mine all around the garage, both to use it and to get it out of the way of other things it's blocking access to. The 3 circular saws I own? not so much...

Comment: @FreeMan The 'to feel safe' was the key phrase really. I don't have a garage I can rearrange to get the board set up as rigidly and with the working space you're imagining even for a jigsaw - it's just that I'd just feel more comfortable with the latter in more cramped and not-so-well-supported conditions than a circular saw. (Especially never having used one before. If you'd be happy using it in a lift even that's up to you.)

Comment: Fair enough. If you're not comfortable, you shouldn't use a power tool, as they can be somewhat dangerous. Not to say you should fear it, but be respectful of the harm it can cause. I was simply trying to understand your situation. FWIW, I usually use 2 saw horses, often set outside on uneven ground (despite the garage), to support a 4x8' sheet of plywood and cut with the circular saw, but if you don't have even that space or feel comfortable with it, then don't do so!

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate To be clear, it's not 'enthusiasm for hand-cut' per se, at least reading that as meaning unpowered - it's plywood after all, I'm not going to be making tiny half-blind dovetails or anything! I'd just a) like to make them by some means; b) like to have them. It's been an intended project for a long time, but had a sudden extra motivation to just get it done recently when what they'll replace broke slightly, hence it slightly sounding like a lack of patience and that I should just buy some in the comment you replied to.

Comment: Just to go back to a question that seems to have gotten lost in the shuffle, if you're buying your ply from the right sort of supplier they may do X number of cuts for free. With this option you can have strips of the major components ready to crosscut to size once you get them home, saving a lot of work (and potentially changing the balance of 'best tool the job' from power tool to hand saw).

Comment: @OJFord — I’m a huge fan of building things. If time/tools/whatever get on top of you and you really just need drawers, then it is possible to order knockdown drawers to exact size and have them in a few days. They are vastly more expensive than building your own from ply, but take far less time.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks yes I did see that - I'll need to order for delivery unfortunately so not really an option. (Apart from specialists I suppose.. might check, but I assume it would be crazy expensive, even if they'd entertain my tiny order - should be able to get it out of one board.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Remember that every sheet of plywood should have two good long edges, two good short edges AND possibly four square corners<sup>1</sup>.* Use this to your advantage if the factory edges are in good condition; and if they're not perhaps a little hand planing or sanding with a block will clean them up enough that you can use them as the bottom edge in drawer boxes.

---

> don't think I have enough space to set up to feel safe using a circular saw (certainly no room for a table saw).

FWIW circular saws are considered *the* tool for making at least the initial break-down cuts on sheet goods, so if you will be using plywood etc. a fair bit one can be a worthwhile purchase. And arguably the safest way to use one to do this is to work on the floor, on top of a sacrificial surface such as thick insulation foam, so the method doesn't require a dedicated workplace.

Also, with just a few scraps of wood and a little ingenuity you can quite easily create a very capable sawing guide, saving 'a little' over some of the commercial track saws ^_^

[image: Circ saw on foam]

> Popular opinion seems to be that you can't cut straight with a (handheld) jigsaw.

Well popular opinion is wrong in this case. As I say in my Comment above, the (many) people who say this are either blindly repeating a 'fact' they've heard, or they're relating their own experience *where they did it wrong*.

Sure, with a jigsaw you won't easily match the kind of cut you can achieve with a table saw, or a circular saw for that matter (even used freehand), but you can cut *at least* as straight as with a panel saw and nobody goes around criticising hand saws for how bad those are at sawing to the line!

Just as when making cuts with a hand saw, so much comes down to the user.

With a jigsaw if you push the cut you're setting yourself up for failure. But slow down and be patient, let the saw do the work, and you can saw to line really well.

> Does the blade really wobble side to side that much?

AFAIK it's not really about blade wobble, it's more about blade deflection (from pushing the cut) which can tend to pull the saw away from the desired path.

Slow right down however and a wandering jigsaw will start to behave itself. Sawing is not a race.

And that's just if sawing freehand. Things get even better if you jig it.....

[image: Sawing Straight with the Jigsaw]

> Can plywood be (hand) planed, or does the glue gum up too much?

Obviously plywood quality varies (lots) but yes you can definitely plane it.

You'll probably find you need to re-hone your iron a little more frequently than normal, but not excessively so. I recently had to plane quite a bit of OSB which is way tougher than a typical plywood, and even that wasn't too bad<sup>2</sup>.

Watch out for spelching at the corners due to every second ply being at right angles to the edge, and utilise one of the [end-grain planing tricks](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/741/how-do-you-plane-end-grain/753#753) for clean corners.

**What plane to use**
Honestly just about anything. If the drawers you plan to make are not small you could do with using a no. 4 or 5 for their longer soles, but you can do this quite well with a block plane. Just needs a little more care to ensure your edges end up straight if you're using a shorter plane.

Regardless of the plane you use having the iron nice and sharp will of course pay dividends.

---

### Sawing plywood by hand

I don't want to dissuade you from trying to saw sheet goods by hand, because with one of the better modern panel saws with tough, hardened teeth and the right setup (saw horses etc.) you can break down plywood surprisingly quickly<sup>3</sup> and easily by hand.

Your first few cuts are unlikely to be the straightest ever made naturally, but as you're already committed to cleaning up the sawn edges by planing as long as you stick to the waste side of the line it sorta doesn't matter :-) And you will get better at it with practice.

So don't dismiss it as unworkable method, despite the undeniable advantages of doing it with a power saw. Sometimes it's just way faster to do it by hand, and *good enough*.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least two have a reputation for being reliably square, but never take this for granted. *Always* check.

<sup>2</sup> And this was with stock irons in very much non-premium planes, so not using A2, PMV-11 or anything like that :-)

<sup>3</sup> 3/4" material saws at approx. one inch per stroke [according to Jim Tolpin](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/how-can-i-accurately-cross-cut-a-board-that-is-too-wide-for-my-table-saw/5360#5360).

Comment: Great answer, many thanks. I know they're 'the tool' to use, (and all else equal would be my preference) which is why I pre-emptively asked 'without'.. but I must admit it hadn't occurred to me to do it on the floor. I'd need to be absolutely sure I was only sacrificing the sacrificial material though, insulation might be a bit riskily compressible for that? I suppose I could have some sacrificial-if-necessary wood underneath it.

Comment: Welcome. The standard material for this is some kind of rigid foam. Perhaps *the* choice is the pink stuff, you see that in so many pics & vids. But I deliberately didn't use a photo of that because obvs it's not about the colour, it's the *type* of material that matters. Now you don't have to use foam of course, there are other sacrificial materials you can use, including MDF (which is what many cutting tables have as their replaceable top). But for the floor some sort of rigid foam seems the ideal solution and because it's much thicker than most MDF it's more forgiving on depth. Cheaper too.

Comment: 'Rigid foam' = expanded polystyrene ('XPS'/'EPS') right? (edit: there seems to be a distinction between extruded=XPS & expanded=EPS...) I do have some scrap MDF, probably not thick enough to use on its own though, unless I also lifted it up off the floor a bit with some smaller scraps. As you say though EPS is cheap, I suppose I have the fluffy rolls of insulation in mind, but I just imagine being worried it'll squash a bit and I'll end up with a nice new pattern in the floor. Might have to go and have a look at some first, or watch some videos.

Comment: I was under the impression the pink stuff was something different to expanded polystyrene, but a quick Google search says it is actually. The stuff in the image I posted does appear to be EPS judging by most of the word Styrene being visible on the face.

Comment: Oh I actually assumed that was the brand Styrofoam that was stamped on it. Having watched a few YouTube videos on it, I was coming to the conclusion that it is something different (but I don't know what, they all just called it 'rigid foam' or similar as you did) - might not be available here in the UK though, if it is, from what I can see.

Comment: Ah you're in the UK. There's a dense insulation foam called PIR on our side of the pond that might be the right stuff, it used to be super expensive but the price has dropped since last time I checked so it's affordable now.